# How to make input part of my code?

Tags: c++, math, input

So I have this maths project where I have to write a program which calculates definite integral of a given function within the given boundaries. I've done this using C++ and CodeBlocks, but now I would like to try and make it possible to input function using cmd when I run my code in CodeBlocks, just like I input boundaries, so I don't have to edit this line of code every time I want to run it for different function. I realised that this would require actually using then this input ( e.g. "sqrt(pow(x,2)-1)" ) as part of the code when entered, and I really don't know how to do this or if it is possible at all, so any help is welcome.
This the part of the code which handles function:

```
double Formula(double x)
{
    double a;
    a = sqrt(x);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I know that not easy on just using only C / C++. You should parse functional words (like sqrt, pow), variable (like x), constant (2, 1) and convert to function with parameters (even skip error case). Do you know lex, yacc? I think also can be helpful.

Comment: @Yoon-Geun Kwon: Yes I recommand to use lex and yacc too, but if it's just a little project it will be overkill. upvoted.

Comment: @Yoon-GeunKwon : Thanks for the advice, I'll check out those tools and try to make something out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evaluate expression like "sqrt(pow(x,2)-1)", you have to:

1. parse the string and generate an AST (Abstract syntax tree) which describes the operations to execute
2. use an evaluation function on the AST

For example, if you have "sqrt(pow(x,2)-1)" in input, the AST could be represented like this:

- function - sqrt

  - function - substract

    - function - pow

      - variable - x
      - integer - 2
    - integer - -1

You have to define the structures which will be used to represent your AST.

Then, to parse the query string you have 2 choices:

- parse it yourself, count the parentheses etc...
- use a tool to generate the parser: yacc + lex or under linux bison + flex. These tools require time to be used to them.

If you have just a little project to do, you may have to try to parse the input yourself to generate the AST.

If the project is a compilation project, you should use bison + flex, they are exactly made for that (but require time to be used to ! ).

Comment: Parsing, AST's, etc, etc are outside the scope of this question most likely.

Comment: very thorough explanation, I appreciate it, it will turn out to be the most difficult part of the project, but I'll try implementing it anyway seems interesting

Comment: You may want to look at the calculator example in http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, integrate with a scripting language, make it do the function parsing and evaluation. It will be considerably slower though.

JavaScript interpreters are all over the place. Python is fairly popular, too. Some people like Lua.